# Kofax.BatchCreate: Are batches created synchronously or Asynchronously?

Tags: api, kofax

When using the *Kofax Capture Document Access API* are batches created immediately, or does one have to check back later to see if the batch was successfully created (I can't find anything either way in the documentation)

I ask because the Web Service API documentation says you send a "Create Batch" request with the details of the batch, then later you need to check to see if the batch was successfully created.

This mirrors the Batch XML workflow where a folder is polled for files, and you later check back to see if the file was correctly processed.

So the question is, when using the .Net/COM API is the batch created synchronously, or will I also have to check later for batch success?

*Some background: We currently have solutions that use Batch XML files and are investigating other options, I don't have access to an Ascent server at the moment, we're waiting on eval licences etc, otherwise I'd try it myself*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batch is created synchronously when you use the .Net/COM API.  In my previous job, I used that API a LOT.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Batches with the webservice is diffrent and through the .net API is differenet. Prefer the .net one only for the synchronously creating